# Add to ContainerViews in a loop

Tags: swift

I want to use containerviews to contain three instances of a collectionview.

My outlets are:

```
@IBOutlet weak var topContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var middleContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomContainer: UIView!
```

I can do it: with a disgusting solution with repeating code in viewdidload:

```
    topContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    middleContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bottomContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // add child view controller view to container
    if let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collectionscroll") as? CollectionScrollViewController {
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topContainer.addSubview(controller.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainer.bottomAnchor)
            ])
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    if let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collectionscroll") as? CollectionScrollViewController {
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        middleContainer.addSubview(controller.view)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: middleContainer.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: middleContainer.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: middleContainer.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: middleContainer.bottomAnchor)
            ])
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)

    }


    if let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collectionscroll") as? CollectionScrollViewController {
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomContainer.addSubview(controller.view)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomContainer.bottomAnchor)
            ])
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)

    }
```

So to cut out repeating code I think of using a looop:

```
lazy var containers : [UIView] = [topContainer, middleContainer, bottomContainer]

    for container in containers {
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collectionscroll") as? CollectionScrollViewController {
            addChild(controller)
            controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            topContainer.addSubview(controller.view)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor),
                controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor),
                controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
                controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor)
                ])
            controller.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }
```

Yet it doesn't work - the middle view does not populate and the last one does not scroll.

How can I populate my containers without copy pasta codez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one error.  When you transformed the code by adding the loop, you forgot to change one of the `topContainer`s to `container`.

Change:

```
topContainer.addSubview(controller.view)
```

to:

```
container.addSubview(controller.view)
```